# Xamarin - How to call click event on user control?

Tags: android, ios, user-controls, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin.forms PCL having android and IOS project

I create one usercontrol (two label in stacklayout)

I want to create click event for usercontrol.

below is following code:

.xaml Code

```
  <local:DashboardBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" SLBGColor ="#2E74B5"  BoxTitle="&#x0a; + &#x0a; Income">
  <local:DashboardBox.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="onInComeTapped"/>
  </local:DashboardBox.GestureRecognizers>
</local:DashboardBox>
```

.cs Code

```
    async void onInComeTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Income());
    }
```

UserControl code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="BudgetManager.Control.DashboardBox">
<StackLayout x:Name="SL"  WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150" Padding="0,10,0,10">
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Label x:Name="lblTitle" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="White" FontSize="20"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
  <Label x:Name="lblValue"  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Grid.Row="1"  TextColor="White" FontSize="20"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"> </Label>


</Grid>
</StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

When I click on usercontrol event "onIncomeTapped" does not called

Please suggest me how to call click event on usercontrol.

Comment: What type is your DashboardBox? When you put in a breakpoint does it get hit?

Comment: Dashboard is user control that I make. When I hit i am not getting any event call

Comment: I understand but can you show the code for it? Please update your question

Comment: This all depends on what type of control `DashboardBox` is

Comment: I added usercontrol design code in question

Comment: I made a basic demo but didn't reproduce your problem. Could you please set a debug point on the row and check if the codes get triggered or not? If not, could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?